# variable argument type in va_arg function in c

Tags: c

I'm getting a warning by the gcc compiler and the program aborts if the following code is executed I couldn't get why? Would be great help if someone clarified it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
int f(char c,...);
int main()
{
   char c=97,d=98;
   f(c,d);
   return 0;
}

int f(char c,...)
{
   va_list li;
   va_start(li,c);
   char d=va_arg(li,char); 
   printf("%c\n",d);
   va_end(li);
}
```

GCC tells me this:

```
warning: 'char’ is promoted to ‘int’ when passed through ‘...’ [enabled by default]
note: (so you should pass ‘int’ not ‘char’ to ‘va_arg’)
note: if this code is reached, the program will abort
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arguments to variadic functions undergo *default argument promotions*; anything smaller than an `int` (such as `char`) is first converted to an `int` (and `float` is converted to `double`).

So `va_arg(li,char)` is never correct; use `va_arg(li,int)` instead.

Comment: Why is it not mentioned in k&r book?

Comment: Interesting enough some compilers have a `va_arg()` that will round up to an `int` if you use `char`. The Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 has as its `va_arg()` the following: `#define _crt_va_arg(ap,t)    ( *(t *)((ap += _INTSIZEOF(t)) - _INTSIZEOF(t)) )` with the additional macro definition of `#define _INTSIZEOF(n)   ( (sizeof(n) + sizeof(int) - 1) & ~(sizeof(int) - 1) )`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this appears to be a quirk in C standard. However, it looks like this is only to do with `va_arg()`.

You can take a look at various implementations of `printf()` to see how to overcome this. For example, the [one in klibc](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/libs/klibc/klibc.git/tree/usr/klibc/vsnprintf.c) is pretty easy to read.